# Error when overloading << "Exception thrown: read access violation.m.matrix was 0xCDDDCDDE."

Tags: c++, overloading

**I want to overload operator of stream << for class CMatrix and there is popping out error**

> "Exception thrown: read access violation.m.matrix was 0xCDDDCDDE."

### **when it's trying to read m.matrix(debugging stops right there with error).**

```
class CMatrix : IMatrix
{
protected:
    uint32_t rows;
    uint32_t columns;
    double **matrix;
public:
    CMatrix(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns);
    CMatrix(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns, double **mat);
~CMatrix();
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &stream, const CMatrix &m);
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & stream, const CMatrix & m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.columns; j++)
        {
            stream << m.matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        stream << endl;
    }
    return stream;
}

CMatrix::CMatrix(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns, double * mat)
{
    this->rows = rows;
    this->columns = columns;
    double** matrix = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i<this->rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[columns];
        memcpy(matrix[i], &mat[i * this->columns], sizeof(double)*this->columns);
    }
}
CMatrix::~CMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)                                            
    {
        delete[] matrix[i];                                                 
    }
    matrix = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new

Comment: Show the code for the constructors. The bug is likely there.

Comment: The Rule of Three has not been observed. [What is the Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Click the link and find out.

Comment: This is rather a side note of the problem at hand, but you should get in the habit of naming constructor parameters different from class members. For instance if you're using `uint32_t rows;` in your class, your constructor parameters should be something different such as `uint32_t _rows, uint32_t _columns);` Eliminates ambiguity.

Comment: @PureVision your comment almost nailed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in `CMatrix::CMatrix(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns, double * mat)`

```
double** matrix = new double*[rows];
```

shadows member

```
double **matrix;
```

The constructor allocates and initializes storage that is pointed at by an Automatic (also known as local) variable. This local `matrix` is lost when the constructor ends, and the member `matrix` goes uninitialized and points Crom knows where, leading to the crash when it is accessed.

Solution:

```
CMatrix::CMatrix(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns, double * mat)
{
    this->rows = rows;
    this->columns = columns;
    matrix = new double*[rows]; // don't create a new variable. Use the member 
    for (int i = 0; i<this->rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[columns];
        memcpy(matrix[i], &mat[i * this->columns], sizeof(double)*this->columns);
    }
}
```

or better

```
CMatrix::CMatrix(uint32_t rows, uint32_t columns, double * mat) : 
    rows(rows), columns(columns), matrix(new double*[rows])
{
    for (int i = 0; i<this->rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[columns];
        memcpy(matrix[i], &mat[i * this->columns], sizeof(double)*this->columns);
    }
}
```

That colon at the end of the parameter list starts a [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

However be aware that `std::vector` will make this job much, much easier by allowing `CMatrix` to take advantage of [the Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: It works ! Thank you @user4581301. I've got one more question , how will look like destructor for this?because my old one doesn't work and pops out the same error. I've edited main thread and added destructor.

Comment: @WojtekPtasinski if ` for (int i = 0; i<this->rows; i++) { delete[] matrix[i]; } delete[] matrix;` does not work, you have probably run afoul of `CMatrix` not observing [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), but to be sure you should ask a new question. No point muddying the waters on this one.